# jquery: move (sets) of TR to a newly moved TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first of, thank you for taking the time to read this, I will try my best to  explain what I'm trying to achieve using jquery, I am currently stuck on moving sets of TRs on a new position. I can move the headers just fine.

here is what my generated table looks like:

```
<table border="1">
<thead class='thx'> ..tr th here
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="gheader" colspan="2">header1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="glabel"><label id="label1">label1</label></td>
 <td class="ginput"><input class="checkbox" id="inputcheckbox1" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="gheader" colspan="2">header2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="glabel"><label id="label2">label2</label></td>
 <td class="ginput"><input class="checkbox" id="inputcheckbox2" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

next:
I want to new move the TD's beside the first (td.class>gheader) .. yes this is possible / done. so now, my table looks like:

```
<table>
<thead class='thx'> ..tr th here
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="gheader">header1</td>
 <td class="gheader">header2</td>
..and so on
</tr>
<tr>
```

now here is where my problem lies:
upon moving the generated td's with class gheader ( header1,header2,header3 ) to be on the same row how can I move the following:

```
<tr>
 <td>label(id)</td>
 <td>checkbox(id)</td>
<tr>
```

in between each headers which was newly moved

possible table output would look like:

```
<table border="1">
<thead class='thx'>
<tr>
<td class="gheader" colspan="2">h</td>
<td class="gheader" colspan="2">i</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="gheader" colspan="2">header1</td>
<td class="gheader" colspan="2">header2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="glabel"><label id="label1">label1</label></td>
<td class="ginput"><input class="checkbox" id="inputcheckbox1" type="text" value="">    </td>

 <td class="glabel"><label id="label2">label2</label></td>
 <td class="ginput"><input class="checkbox" id="inputcheckbox2" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

other notes:
colspan 2 (on gheader) is auto generated

Comment: What's the issue? You just move the nodes like you'd move any other nodes. If you accomplished the first part, I can't see why you couldn't do this too. And BTW, you should just skip to the relevant part of your question. The top half that you already accomplished really didn't add anything.

Comment: is it absolutely necessary to transform the table? might be a generation desirable code from first try will be better?

Comment: BlueSkies, I just added the top half for information purposes. thank you for your input.
RubenKazumov, yes generating a desirable code would be better but it will mean all other generated tables will look the same, I am just transforming this specific table for a report.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $tbody = $('table tbody');
$tbody.find('.gheader').appendTo($tbody.find('tr:first-child'));
$tbody.find('tr').slice(1).find('td').appendTo($tbody.find('tr:nth-child(2)'));
$tbody.find('tr').slice(2).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4c9gf/)